# Jordi Gali optimal price setting

Tags: macroeconomics, new-keynesian-economics

Monetary Policy, Inflation,
and the Business Cycle, 
Jordi Gali,
Page 45
http://elib.peaceland.edu.ng:8383/greenstone3/sites/localsite/collect/peacelan/index/assoc/HASH0139.dir/doc.pdf

How does "ψ " convert to "MC"?

You can say Drago Bergholt solutions for Gali
http://bergholt.weebly.com/uploads/1/1/8/4/11843961/the_basic_new_keynesian_model_-_drago_bergholt.pdf
but Drago also didn't explain this change. (page 13 )

Sincerely

Comment: I think you should solve the whole model to see this since the very beginning because for someone who is just looking on this equation can not say you how to proceed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third line of p.45 denotes:

$MC_{t+k|t}=\psi_{t+k|t}/P_{t+k}$

but this is probably not the answer you are looking for.

Going from eq. (9) to (10), multipliy the right-hand side by $\frac{P_{t+k}}{P_{t+k}}=1$ (you can always multiply by one), the numerator goes into $\Pi_{t-1,t+k}$ (together with $P_{t-1}$), the denominator goes into $MC_{t+k|t}=\psi_{t+k|t}/P_{t+k}$.

Comment: @EnginYILMAZ You are welcome! If you're satisfied with the response, please consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer on the left, such that it shows up as "answered" on the website.